# error: (-215:Assertion failed) trainDescCollection[iIdx].rows < IMGIDX_ONE in function 'knnMatchImpl'. For the first few images it worked perfectly

Tags: python, image, opencv, feature-detection, sift

For the first few iterations it worked perfectly but later on it throw out the same error not sure what exactly is happening..

```
im1_new=cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

im2_new=cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp1,des1=sift.detectAndCompute(im1_new,None)
kp2,des2=sift.detectAndCompute(im2_new,None)

matcher = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches=matcher.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
```

Comment: Please provide the error code and more details

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.